Where to install water arrestors
I installed eater preassure reducing valve and some weeks after I started getting water hammer. It is mostly felt from toilet (which has biobidet on it) but it seems to be hammering mostly in the other bathroom wall. Where shall I put water arrestor? Should it be at last faucet or somewhere in the middle between toilet and last faucet?

See: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/207867/18078

The first step is finding what fixture is causing the water hammer. It will be a fixture that has a solenoid valve, such as a dishwater or a clothes washer. In your case, the bidet toilet seat would have a solenoid valve.
Does the water hammer occur when using the bidet toilet seat? The hammer noise may not happen at the fixture. The sudden stop of water flow causes a shock wave to travel back through the piping. The location where it is heard will depend on the configuration of your piping system.
If the water hammer occurs when using the bidet toilet seat, you can install an in-line water hammer arrestor that connects to the compression valve that serves your toilet. Similar to the image below:

Image source: Homedepot.com

UPC PLUMBING CODE.
Says to install on all quick closing valves. Such as ice maker, dishwasher, washing machines, Sloan valves, solenoid valves.
